# What happens when you type Exit in the CMD window on Server Core in an RDP session

Tags: rdp, windows-command-prompt, windows-server-core

I'm getting used to Server Core and I know at some point I am going to type "Exit" in the command window while connected through a remote desktop session.

I know that if this is done while connected to the local console, you can press Ctl-Alt-Del to bring up the Task Manager and select New Task and run CMD.EXE to get the Command Window back.

However, you can't press CTRL-ALT-DEL in an RDP session.

So before I make this mistake I thought I would find out what happens and how I go about getting a Command Window back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> brings up the task manager directly. You can launch it from there.

Alternatively, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> will send a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> to the RDP session if you want to take the long way.

Comment: Did not know that one.  Good to know.  I feel like I'm a 1000 years behind on keyboard shortcuts...

Comment: Unusual situation, but I was super stuck and wanted to share: If you have a server core RDP inside of a regular server RDP (e.g., you're using a bastion host) and you can't make the outside RDP fullscreen, make the core RDP fullscreen, then bring up the onscreen keyboard in the regular RDP and then try these commands.